# AucTeX preview-latex not working

Tags: auctex, preview-latex

When i'm working in a LaTeX-File everything works as expected. Compilation and completion via company-auctex are working perfectly. However when i want to make use of any preview-functionality inside my editing buffer (For example with C-c C-p C-p "preview at point" there is no preview, but an error buffer that ends with

```
Preview-PDF2DSC finished at Mon Mar 26 10:30:58
Running `Preview-Ghostscript' with ``/usr/bin/rungs -dOutputFile\=\ 
(_region_.prv/tmp696XBB/pr1-\%d.png\) -q -dDELAYSAFER -dNOPAUSE - 
DNOPLATFONTS -dPrinted -dTextAlphaBits\=4 -dGraphicsAlphaBits\=4 - 
sDEVICE\=png16m -r86.5414x86.6274''

Preview-Ghostscript exited abnormally with code 1 at Mon Mar 26 
10:30:58
Unable to read environment locale:exit now.

Preview-Ghostscript exited abnormally with code 1
```

Configuration and AucTeX-setup is just

```
(use-package auctex
  :defer t
  :ensure t)
```

Does anyone have an idea what to do? Is maybe something missing in my config?

Emacs Version: 25.3.1
AucTeX Version: 12.1.1
Ghostscript Version: 9.22

All help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: It seems that Ghostscript isn't happy due to missing locale value: `Unable to read environment locale`.  Maybe you check and set that and try it again.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Could you maybe tell me, how i would do that?

Comment: You can check the values by doing `locale RET` in a shell.  For setting the values, I suggest you check the documentation of your distro and/or search the web.

Comment: It seems like kde has automatically set my locales to be de_EN.UTF8 because i'm in Germany but prefer english as my OS-Language! However i changed it to de_DE.UTF8 and now preview functionality works. Thanks for your guidance @ArashEsbati